# Smooth Function Question

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Define a function $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, to be $C^k$ if all $k$-th partial derivatives exist and are continuous at $p$. $f$ is said to be $C^k$ on a set $U$ if it is $C^k$ at all $p$ in $U$. Let us say $f$ is $C^{\infty}$ at $p$ if all partial derivatives exist and are continuous at $p$. $f$ is $C^{\infty}$ on $U$ if it is at every $p$ in $U$.

I am working on a question and was hoping someone can clarify something. Consider the function $f(x) = x^{1/3}$. Now, clearly, this function is $C^0$ but not $C^1$ at $x=0$. In general, the $n$-th derivative is:

$$f^{(n)}(x) = \frac{(-1)^nB_n}{3^n}\cdot x^{(1-3n)/3},$$ 
where $B_n = \{1,2,10,80,\cdots\}$ for $x=0$ and undefined for $x=0$.

I believe this tells us that $f$ is in fact $C^{\infty}$ on the set $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. Is this correct?

P.S One could probably find a closed form solution for $B_n$ but it is not really relevant to the question.

Comment: Yep, seems legit.

Comment: Why the differential geometry tag?! You can deduce the result immediately by applying the inverse function theorem to $g(x)=x^3$ on $\Bbb R-\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The $n$-th derivative is not true. I think the power of $x$ should be $(1-3n)/3$.

$B_{n}=2*5*8*...*(3n-4)$ for $n$ more than $1$.

The differentiability of a map is usually discussed point-wise. Here at every point $p$ of $R\{0}$ you can get a sufficiently small disc about it where your map is clearly infinitely differentiable at $p$ and at every point of the disc.

Comment: Yes, it should be 1-3n / 3. That was a typo. Regarding the tag, this is a question from a textbook I am reading on differential manifolds.